# Getting a java agent has been loaded warning in intelliJ after upgrading JDK 17 to 21

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have just upgraded from JDK 17 to 21 in my Windows machine. After that when I am running JUNIT test in my IntelliJ I am getting the following warring. I have looked over all of the day, but no solution worked for me. Any feedback please:

[image]

Comment: See [JEP 451: Prepare to Disallow the Dynamic Loading of Agents](https://openjdk.org/jeps/451). If you're using Mockito in your tests, then also take a look at [JDK 21 - Dynamic Loading of Agent (byte-buddy-agent-1.14.4.jar) #3037](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/3037). The likely easiest solution is to pass `-XX:+EnableDynamicAgentLoading` when executing your tests, though all that will do is hide the warning, and might eventually stop working in a future release.

Comment: Based on that JEP and the discussion in the GItHub issue, the proper fix is to load Byte Buddy as an agent (i.e., via `-javaagent`) instead of as a library (i.e., via `--class-path` or `--module-path`). However, it appears that neither IDEs nor build tools make this particularly easy, so properly fixing the problem will likely have to wait until IDEs and build tools "catch up". That said, *I believe* the GItHub issue has a comment somewhere that shows a solution/workaround for Maven (which you appear to be using).

Comment: Do not use images for logs.

Comment: How can I pass -XX:+EnableDynamicAgentLoading ? Where should I exactly write this? @Slaw

Comment: Depends on what is executing your tests (Maven, IntelliJ, etc.). Look up how to pass JVM arguments to your tests in whatever tool you're using.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same warning.

In our case (I assume you, like me, are using IntelliJ "run configurations" to execute tests), it can be solved by adding the abovementioned parameter "-XX:+EnableDynamicAgentLoading" to the surefire plugin in your `pom.xml` file:

```xml
      <!-- maven surefire -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <argLine>-XX:+EnableDynamicAgentLoading</argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Now the warning is gone when running tests from within IntelliJ.

Answer (score 2):

In case if you are using Gradle, you can add these options to your build configuration to get rid of the warnings.

build.gradle:

```
test {
// previous JVM options
jvmArgs("-noverify", "-XX:+EnableDynamicAgentLoading", "-Djdk.instrument.traceUsage") // add this
}
```

After making this change, rebuild your project.